# Android Webview Upload Image from gallery or camera

Tags: java, android, webview, image-uploading

Hey and thanks for your time.
In my page that is loaded in the webview of my app is a photo upload:

```
<form action="?pb=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="pbbutton" type="file" title="Profielbild ändern" name="datei" onchange="this.form.submit()">

<label id="pblabel" for="pbbutton"><img  id="profilbild" title="Profilbild ändern" class="userpb" src="./users/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userid); ?>/pb" alt="Bild nicht gefunden" onerror="this.src='./img/no_pb.png';"></label>

</form>
```

It uploades a photo if you usually pic one of your gallery etc...

How can I make, that if I click on this input, that I can choose a picture and than the webside detects the change (js: onchange)
I already tried something but it wont upload the picture after I selected it.
Here my coding for the imgupload:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



//For IMG Upload
private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            Uri[] results = null;
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }
                Uri result = null;
                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }






    /**
 * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
 * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
 */
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
        // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }

}

    WebView mWebView;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
            // carry on the normal flow, as the case of  permissions  granted.
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
        // Below required for geolocation
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/noinet.html");

            }
        });
        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtivity.org");

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            //FOR IMG UPLOAD
            // For Android 5.0
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePath;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            }

        });

    }






    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Pop the browser back stack or exit the activity
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help and have a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check My answer maybe helps you I had same problem but I solve like this :

[Input type file cannot work browse option in android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419159/input-type-file-cannot-work-browse-option-in-android-webview/46420185#46420185)